# Is there a way to know when is the last time I ran a program in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way to know when is the last time I ran a program in IntelliJ? Doesn't need to be specific, just a date will work! Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the most robust answer which could be given here, but one quick and dirty way would be to check the last modified timestamps of the `target` folders of each of your IntelliJ projects.  Presumably, when you run a given a project in IntelliJ, it would do a build, thereby updating the `target` folder.  The latest date you find among your projects might be the last time you ran something.  Of course, if you re-ran a project which did not require a rebuild, then this method might not be completely accurate.